# How to run a workflow that searches for values and stores them in another type?

Tags: bubble.io

I have 2 tables (or types). User, and Match. In table User, I have an one field for email address, and another one for a list of values, like A,B,C.

I'm trying to create the following logic:

For every entry (or thing) in User, in a field A (which is a list):
Take every item in the list, search for every other entry (or thing) in User in field A.
When a current users item in field A = another user’s item in field A,

Then

In type Match, create a new thing,
In Field A store the value that matched,
In field B, Store the current user’s email address, and
In-field C put the email address that belongs to the field where the value matched.

Is this even possible;e? It seems simple but I don’t know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a third table called "Values".

Then make the field which contains one or more values ("A", "B", "C") a List of Values (basically, a list of the "Values" object type).

Then, create a workflow that searches all of the values and apply the "Unique Elements" filter.

Then, use "Schedule workflow on a list", to run a backend workflow where each item searches itself (Values where the value is the item's value). If the "Count" of the search > 1, then search for users that have that value, and create a new item in Matches for each.